configuring CMK on synapse workspace getting the error Could not perform a 'Get' operation on the workspace encryption key
I have got a synapse workspace bicep code below, trying to add double encryption but currently faced with the error below.
key: {
  name: 'default'
  keyVaultUrl: 'https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/keys/key-name'

}

Could not perform a 'Get' operation on the workspace encryption key. Make sure that the secret identifier is a valid key url and the workspace Managed Identity has 'Get', 'WrapKey' and 'UnwrapKey' access to the KeyVault through the KeyVault's Access Policies or through RBAC. (Code: CustomerManagedKeyPermissionMissing)
Checked the managed identity, granted key vault administrator role as well as the Key Vault Crypto User role. Unsure as to what the issue could be and whether what i am trying to achieve is actually possible.
Reading the page here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/729412/arm-deployment-of-synapse-analytics-with-cmk suggests that when behind a firewall, this may not work. In my case, the environment is all behind a private endpoint.
resource create_synapse_workspace 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: synapse_workspace_name
  location: location
  tags: my_tags
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned,UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${synapse_identity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    defaultDataLakeStorage: {
      createManagedPrivateEndpoint: false
      accountUrl: accountURL
      filesystem: filesystem
    }
    // encryption: {}

    encryption: {
      cmk: {
        kekIdentity: {
          userAssignedIdentity: mi
          useSystemAssignedIdentity: false
        }
        key: {
          name: 'default'
          keyVaultUrl: 'https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/keys/key-name'

        }
      }
    }
    managedVirtualNetwork: 'default'
    managedResourceGroupName: null 
    sqlAdministratorLogin: adminaccount
    sqlAdministratorLoginPassword: adminpassword
    privateEndpointConnections: [
    ]
    managedVirtualNetworkSettings: {
      preventDataExfiltration: false
    }
    workspaceRepositoryConfiguration: {
      accountName: account_name
      collaborationBranch: branch
      repositoryName: repo
      rootFolder: folder
      type: type
    }

    trustedServiceBypassEnabled: false    
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
  }

}


It looks much like the issue is in locating your key in the keyvault. I have had such before it’s likely a bug. Can you use the url to point to an exact version string for a test.  ‘https://.vault.azure.net/keys//’ . Use the actual key-version (something like 036xxx not latest)
The roles for the managed identity looks right to me. Ensure you are using the right user managed identity and in the same region as the kv and other resources.
